# How should I understand the noise variance parameter(s) in multifidelity modeling using Emukit

Tags: gaussian-process, hyperparameter, noise

I am learning the multi-fidelity modeling and have a question about Emukit's `mixed_noise` parameters, or more general, how should we determine the noise when the training data are simulation results, which can be assumed to be exact/noise-free according to the book Gaussian processes for machine learning.

In Emukit's tutorial, it says:

> > Note: The model implementation defaults to a MixedNoise noise likelihood whereby there is independent Gaussian noise for each fidelity.
>
> This can be modified upfront using the 'likelihood' parameter in the model constructor, or by updating them directly after the model has been created. In the example below, we choose to fix the noise to '0' for both fidelities in order to reflect that the observations are exact.

and in the example:

```
gpy_lin_mf_model.mixed_noise.Gaussian_noise.fix(0)
gpy_lin_mf_model.mixed_noise.Gaussian_noise_1.fix(0)
```

In my work, the high and low fidelity observations are both simulation results from two different mesh refinement levels. Should I simply fix both noise variance to be 0 like this tutorial example "*in order to reflect that the observations are exact*"? Or should I just fix the noise variance to be zero and try to quantify/determine the noise for the low fidelity? If yes, how should I derive a reasonable parameter?

Also, I'm not sure if this mental image is correct: now I see the discrepancy term $\gamma(\mathbf{x})$ in linear multi-fidelity modeling $f_t(\mathbf{x}) = \rho f_{t-1}^* (\mathbf{x}) + \gamma(\mathbf{x}) $ is such a Gaussian process, it samples at the shared points between high and low fidelities (most methods assume nested DoE) and the target value is the difference among those shared points. Hence the two fidelities can *both* be exact right? In fact, it makes the prediction of the errors more confident, doesn't it?

I appreciate your comments and insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your numerical models are deterministic, it makes perfect sense to set the noise variance to zero at both levels.  It may sound like a contradiction but it is not: by doing so, you are simply indicating that, at each level $t$, you are making "exact" (noiseless) observations of the corresponding function $f_t$.

As a consequence, the resulting surrogate model will be interpolating in the following sense: if you have observed $y_i = f_{t_i}(x_i)$ and ask for a prediction of the model response at level $t = t_i$ and input $x = x_i$, the predicted value will be $y_i$.  (Of course,the predicted value will not, in general, be the same if you make a prediction at a different level $t' \neq t_i$.)

Note that it is not mandatory to use an noiseless/interpolating GP model when the measurement are "exact" (deterministic numerical model).  Indeed, even then, it is sometimes beneficial to create a surrogate model that is an approximation but not an interpolation.  In this vein you can look for instance at the following papers:

- Gramacy & Lee (2012).  *Cases for the nugget in modeling computer experiments*.  Statistics and Computing, 22:713–722. [DOI:10.1007/s11222-010-9224-x](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-010-9224-x) ⇒ In this paper the authors argue that using a non-zero nugget might be beneficial for the global approximation quality of the surrogate model, if when the numerical model is deterministic.
- Petit et al (2022).  *Relaxed Gaussian process interpolation: a goal-oriented approach to Bayesian optimization*.  [arXiv:2206.03034](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03034) ⇒ In this paper we propose a more sophisticated approach to relax the interpolation constraint only outside a particular region of interest.  This is suitable, for instance, if the resulting GP model is meant to be used in Bayesian optimization or set inversion.